# Where in the world are the cool user people of Anime & Manga SE?

Tags: discussion, events

Ever wondered how much of the world our community covers? Well, now you don't have to wonder any more with our **Cool New Map™**! Anyone from the A&M community that's added their own label will show up, so everyone get involved and see where we have left to invade on the planet!

## [Link to the Cool New Map™!](https://www.zeemaps.com/map?group=1566442)

See below for instructions on how to add yourself!

Comment: I'm not sure, but doesn't SE have an API that you can use to generate this information from?

Comment: @PeterRaeves this [map](http://johndbritton.com/stackmaps/) ?

Comment: @septianprimadewa Yeah something like that. Thanks.

Comment: re-featured for 2016 :)

Comment: for real, not a single marker in Japan yet? but the official map @SeptianPrimadewa linked contains a few so I'm relieved :D

Comment: I feel so lonely.

Comment: @Omega let's be lonely together! :)

Comment: id like to consider myself cool..........seeing as my anime collection consists of stuff going back to the 80s and 70s lol

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So, you too wish to be part of the map craze?

Then click [**this handy link**](https://www.zeemaps.com/map?group=1566442), and follow the steps below:

1. Find and click "Map Access" in the top right corner - enter the password, and click unlock. Password (minus quotation marks) is "Pantsu"
2. Hover over the tab "Additions" and then click "Add Marker - Simple"
3. Fill in the info - just stick your username in the Title field, and stick in your town for the location - don't worry about sticking it *right* on your house.
4. Click submit
5. Look and see at all the cool places people come from ^_^